# Power function in Java using recursion

Tags: java, performance, recursion

I'm trying to complete an assignment for my Java class where we are to create an efficient method for solving powers (taking a base to an exponent, defined by user's input).

I have just about everything in place, but the efficient method `pow2` isn't handling odd exponents correctly. It multiplies the base by one more than it's supposed to. What am I missing here?

For instance, if I input 4 as my base and 5 as my exp, the program will spit out 4096 instead of 1024.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyPow {


    public static int countGbl = 0;


    public static double raise(double base, int exp) {

        double b = base;

        for (int i = 1; i < exp; i++){
            countGbl += 1;
            base = base * b;
        }

        return base;
    }


    public static double pow1(double base, int exp) {

        if (base == 0.0) return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        else if (base == 0.0 && exp >= 0) return 0.0;
        else if (exp == 1) return base;
        else if (base > 0 && exp == 0) return 1.0;
        else{
            if (exp < 0){
                base = 1.0/base;
                exp = -exp;
            }

            if (exp % 2 == 0){
                countGbl++;
                return pow1(base, exp/2) * pow1(base, exp/2);
            }
            else {
                countGbl += 2;
                return pow1(base, exp/2) * pow1(base, exp/2) * base;
            }
        }
    }


    public static double pow2(double base, int exp) {
        double temp = raise(base, exp/2);
        double retval = temp*temp;
        if (exp % 2 == 1){
            countGbl++;
            retval *= temp;
        }
        return retval;
        }





    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter base: ");
        double base = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter exp: ");
        int exp = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

        System.out.println(pow2(base, exp));
        System.out.println(countGbl);

    }
}
```

Just an FYI, the reason for the `pow1` method is because we are to write an example method that isn't as efficient as `pow2`.

Also, please ignore `countGbl`. Our professor wants us to count the number of multiplications done during the method calls.

Comment: Here, made an Ideone for you: https://ideone.com/b4d5LN I also suggest you add comments to your code, to explain what the logic behind some of your descisions are. Usually stepping manually through your code, trying to explain every step will force you to run the code through your head, and helps finding logic flaws.

Comment: no need for `raise()` and `pow2()` methods. Just call `pow1(base,exp)` from `main()`. It will return count of multiplications as 19 mind. Then you can add **memoization** to pow1() to limit multiplications.

Comment: Your pow2 method is not recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to make the optimization:

base<sup>exp</sup> = base<sup>exp/2</sup> * base<sup>exp/2</sup> * base

where `exp` is odd, and where `exp/2` is Java's integer division, really also a floor function in math.

However, what you are doing in the odd case is multiplying in another factor of `temp`, which is already calculated to be base<sup>exp/2</sup>.

Multiply `retVal` by `base`, not `temp`.  Change in `pow2`

```
retval *= temp;
```

to

```
retval *= base;
```

Additionally, another optimization would be instead of going back to the `raise` method after dividing `exp` by 2 in `pow2`, you can keep going with recursion, repeatedly calling `pow2` until you reach a base case of an exponent of 1 or 0.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! retval *= base works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I sketched this recursive solution to your problem, where odds and even exponents are treated directly into `raise`:

```
public static double raise(double base, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0) {
        return 1;
    } if ((exp % 2) == 1) {

        countGbl += 1;
        return raise(base, exp-1) * base;
    } else {
        double tmp = raise(base, exp/2);

        countGbl += 1;
        return tmp * tmp;
    }
}

public static double pow2(double base, int exp) {
    return raise(base, exp);
}
```

Here the number of multiplications is logarithmic with respect to exp.